# Trouble with SVN in Intellij IDEA Community Edition

Tags: svn, intellij-idea

1. I get latest Slik SVN and download my project: svn co https://mycompany.com/svn/product/
2. I get latest Tortoise SVN and it browses it fine
3. I run latest Community edition IDEA, try to get file history but see an error:

Problems whlie loading file history: svn: The path 'C:\Projects\product\myfolder\subfolder1\subfolder2' appears to be part of subversion 1.7 (SVNKit 1.4) or greater 
working copy rooted at 'C:\Projects\Product'
Please upgrade your subversion (SVNKit) client to use this working copy.

What can help me? Can I hack something? What is SVNKit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your IDEA version [doesn't support Subversion 1.7](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2011/12/subversion-17-support-update/) working copies format. As a workaround checkout the project from IDEA or try [11.1 EAP version](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+11.1+EAP) that has experimental support for Subversion 1.7.